# Generating Etags from the result of a semi-lengthy operation?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, etag

I'm trying to get my head wrapped around some caching techniques and the one I'm looking at right now is Etags/conditional get. As far as I understand, what you generally do is:

- Make Request. If available, the client provides a hash in the etag header
- Operation runs and gets a result object
- From that result object, you generate an etag through some means such as MD5 hash
- If etag was in request, compare them. If they match, return Content Not Modified, else return content and new etag.

Thinking about the overall picture, I'm a little confused. In all cases, I can see that using a Not Modified response can save you the extra bytes of an unnecessary response body, but what does that do for server processing time? Rather, it seems to do nothing because the server still has to generate the response object which includes all subsequent processes it needs to get there. What if, for instance, the operation is pretty complex and takes a few seconds to finish. Regardless of whether or not the output is the same, it still has to complete the operation in order to generate a hash of the resultant object.

I feel like I'm looking at the purpose of this approach incorrectly. Are etags only to be used with static resources like files rather than resultant resources of various processes? For instance, an image would be a good use of an etag, but what about a report like a sales history? Is this the dividing line between using etags and general caching or am I missing a piece? Examples by scenario would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP's ETag cache mechanism like any other cache mechanism which you probably know. See it as a cache key. You don't generate the key from the result, you take the input parameters.

So let's assume you have the resource "/image?id=bob&dimension=100x100". This would fetch Bob's picture from the database, scale it down to 100x100 and return it to the client. Instead of hashing the scaled image, hash the input parameters: "bob" and "100x100". If your server gets that request it only has to check if Bob exists in the database and return a 304.